# Getting Location Crashes With Fragments (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, location, fragment

Ok, this is a very dumb problem, but it's been stumping me for the past hour.
I'm going to do my best to explain it.

Basically, the app I'm programming has a tabactivity with fragments for the tab pages. One of the tabs displays a list. This list is sorted by the user's distance from certain locations.

So, because I need the user's current location, I've implemented the 2013 location api's in the activity that hosts all of the fragments.

My problem is, when the fragment is created, it sorts the list. But to sort the list, it needs the user's location. However, the user's location has not been determined yet, because the fragment is created before the locationclient is connected in the activity. Because the locationclient hasn't been connected, I get an error that crashes the application.

So to summarize, the fragment is trying to access the location in the oncreateview method, but the app crashes because this method is called before the locationclient connects and gets the location.

I've tried several ways to get around this, but I'm stumped.

Is there a way to delay creation of fragments until the location is determined? I tried putting the fragment/tab creation code within the onConnected() callback, but this is buggy (for example, when the device is rotated, the app crashes).

I'm fairly new to app development, so I may just be misunderstanding the activity lifecycle. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you just do what you need when the connection is established?

Comment: Why would you want to delay the creation of Fragments? Don't try to reinvent how the framework does things, instead build solutions to solve your problems. Why not have your fragment notify your host Activity when it's finished creation and becomes visible, then have the Activity get the location and pass it back to whichever Fragment(s) that needs that data?

Comment: Both of you have said things that went through my thought process. I said I had tried to do the creation of the fragment when the onconnected() callback is called, basically when the location has connected. However, I said I had issues with using that. Also, I'm trying to have the activity notify the fragment, not the other way around.

Comment: you should just have the activity start the location manager then have the fragment pull from the activity the location by some method in the activity ie. `getActivity().getLocation();` get rid of all code that needs the location to run correctly and move it to a method that is run when you have a location. Just let the fragment view load then update it after you have the location